# Reference "auto detected" bean in Spring's context

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I configured spring to auto-detect some DAOS using

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.app" />
<tx:annotation-driven />.

@Repository("transactionDao")
public class TransactionDao {
...
}
```

Now I'm configuring manually in context another bean which references this one.

```
<property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
    <map>
       <entry key="transactionDao" value-ref="transactionDao" />
    </map>
</property>
```

Now Spring's complaining:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionDao' is defined
```

Is it possible to reference auto detected bean inside context?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to reference auto detected bean inside context?
```

Yes it is very much possible.

In order to see why transactionDao bean was not found, you can verify the following things:

1. TransactionDao should be in classpath and lies in some sub-package of com.mycomp.app
2. If Step-1 is already there, run the application with Logger level for **org.springframework** set to DEBUG and you can see in the startup logs of spring which all beans got initialized.